# seaborn/matplotlib change number of columns in legend object

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, legend

I've seen [Creating multi column legend in python seaborn plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834508/creating-multi-column-legend-in-python-seaborn-plot) but I think my question is a bit different. In short, I've got a dataframe that I'm plotting in `seaborn`'s `lmplot` and getting a `FacetGrid`. Trouble is, there are tons of values for `hue` so I get a super long, single column legend. Code example below:

```
ers = sns.lmplot(
    data=emorb,
    x="Pb",
    y="Nd",
    row="Ridge Sys",
    hue="Seg Name",
    scatter=True,
    fit_reg=False,
    scatter_kws={"alpha":0.7, "edgecolor": "w"},
    palette=sns.color_palette("bright", 20),
    legend=True
)

ers.set(ylim=(0.5122,0.5134))
```

I can access the legend object that is created by calling `ers._legend` and this returns an object with type `Legend` (basically, a `matplotlib` object). However, I can't then call to this legend object to change the number of columns, e.g., with:

```
l = ers._legend
l(ncols=9)
```

Any suggestions, or am I missing something perhaps more obvious, such as a way to redraw the legend and specify any parameters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, figured it out:

The `FacetGrid` object has an attribute `fig`, i.e.

```
g = sns.lmplot()
parent_mpl_figure = g.fig
```

And so if I set `legend=False` in `sns.lmplot()`, I can then specify `parent_mpl_figure.legend(labels=[], ncol=9, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))`.

Written cleanly:

```
g = sns.lmplot(legend = False)
parent_mpl_figure = g.fig
parent_mpl_figure.legend(labels = [], ncol = 9, bbox_to_anchor = (1,1))
```

Hope this is instructive for someone else / now to figure out how to have each `Facet` span the full color palette so that different `hue` groups within each `Facet` group are easier to distinguish...